# How can I install the Android SDK 2.3.5 on Eclipse and find out screen specification?

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3, android-screen

I am developing an Android application for Samsung Galaxy  which runs on Android version 2.3.5.
But due to unavailability of hardware I'm using emulator in Eclipse. The SDK manager only showing  packages 2.3.3 after that 3.0 only.

How do I make download that specific version 2.3.5? How do I find out the screen specification (like screen size is medium or large and whether its mdpi or hdpi) for the target?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your target is just 2.3.5 phones! Anyway, just use the 2.3 or the 2.3.3 and  you will be able to run it in your 2.3.5 phone.

For screen specification, try with this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Good luck!